# Get Gem vendor files in asset pipeline path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have created a gem with a vendor directory containing stylesheets and javascripts from [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap) and bootstrap itself.

The directory structure is
bootstrap-sass-gem/vendor/assets/javascripts

and

bootstrap-sass-gem/vendor/assets/stylesheets

I've required the gem in a test project but whenever I try to require something from that gem I receive a `Sprockets::FileNotFound` error.

For instance, in application.css I added `*= require bootstrap`.
bootstrap is located at `bootstrap-sass-gem/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.scss` and so by my reckoning should be included in the asset pipeline.

I'm running RVM Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1.

Here's my config file:

```
 $:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)

 # Maintain your gem's version:
 require "bootstrap-sass-gem/version"

 # Describe your gem and declare its dependencies:
 Gem::Specification.new do |s|
    s.name        = "bootstrap-sass-gem"
    s.version     = BootstrapSassGem::VERSION
    s.authors     = ["James Smith"]
    s.email       = ["James@smithware.co.uk"]
    s.homepage    = "http://www.smithware.co.uk"
    s.summary     = "The Bootstrap-sass project Gemified"
    s.description = "Description of BootstrapSassGem."

    s.files = Dir["{lib,vendor,rdoc}/**/*"] + Dir["*"]
    #s.test_files = Dir["test/**/*"]

    s.require_paths = ["lib/**/*"]

    # We are dependent on the asset pipeline in 3.1.0
    s.add_dependency "rails", "~> 3.1.0"

    # s.add_development_dependency ""
 end
```

Comment: It could be that the question I really want to ask here is: How do I get my gems files on to the asset pipeline automatically?

Comment: Even after manually adding the Gems stylesheets path to the pipeline the bootstrap.scss file is not found.

Comment: I have a *very similar* question, but I'm wondering what's different 8 years later! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58829381/how-to-include-assets-from-one-gem-inside-another-gem

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with my require_paths variable. 
The correct setting should have been:

```
s.require_paths = ["lib"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I solved it adding a dummy engine. This way in rails 3.1 the assets path was added automatically to Rails.application.config.assets.paths.

> Since Rails 3.0, if you want a gem to automatically behave as an
>   engine, you have to specify an Engine for it somewhere inside your
>   plugin’s lib folder.

Comment: @Will You can read about creating a Rails Engine here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Answer (score -1):

i think the asset pipeline expects your files to be named like `bootstrap.css.scss`. and I'm not sure, but maybe you need to define a railtie for your gem for rails to find the vendored stylesheets

Comment: Leaving out .css works fine for me in other places. I've got an engine.rb file in place that gets called in the bootstrap-sass-gem.rb file. Will try the railtie way. Only used the engine way as they use that in the jQuery-rails gem.

Comment: engine should be fine, it's a subclass of railtie. the problem should lie somewhere else then

Comment: Unfortunately had no luck with this for 3 days now. Rails guide says to look at jquery-rails gem but even using that as a template didn't help. I suspect you're right in saying the problem lies elsewhere as even manually adding the path to the Gems stylesheets didn't help.