# Ruby Gem works when pointing to local gem but not once published

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, asset-pipeline

Here is the situation:

I decided to start moving all the js code that I reuse in every project in a gem and created the gem in:

```
/Users/alain/Dropbox/rails_app/alain_toolbox
```

So in my project, to test if things are working, I add this line to the gem file:

```
gem 'alain_toolbox', '=0.0.1', path:'/Users/alain/Dropbox/rails_app/alain_toolbox
```

everything works fine.

Then, I do a

```
gem build alain_toolbox.gemspec 
gem push alain_toolbox-0.0.1.gem
```

and everything seem to work. So I replace the gem require in the gemfile with:

```
gem 'alain_toolbox'
```

then do a bundle and the gem install successfully. The problem is when I open up the app, I get an error that it cant find 'alain_toolbox' in the line

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

and application.js looks like this:

```
//= require alain_toolbox
```

which was working when I was in local.

So the question is: why?(!)

Thx.

Comment: application.js of base app or gem's?

Comment: Perhaps your gem spec doesn't name all the files that should be put in the gem?

Comment: its the app.js of the app which uses the gem. I guess all the files are correctly named since this works when pointing the gem to the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error: I dont know how, but I forgot to do a 'git add' on the asset files. Once the file were added and the gem rebuilt, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#adding-assets-to-your-gems) indicates the gem needs to implement a rails engine.  In addition, the assets would still need to be in one of the specified directories within the gem (app/assets, lib/assets, or vendor/assets).  I'm assuming in the local case somehow your gem is already in that path.

According to [this AsciiCast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline) you can see the asset pipeline paths in the rails console by printing the Rails.application.config.assets.paths configuratio

Related question: [Get Gem vendor files in asset pipeline path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531563/get-gem-vendor-files-in-asset-pipeline-path)

Comment: I already added the engine and the files are in app/assets/javascript/alain_toolbox will test the paths when I am in front of the computer.