# How to include assets from one gem inside another gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm building a gem - a Rails engine - let's call it `my_new_gem` - and inside of `my_new_gem` I'm trying to include JavaScript assets from another gem - let's call it `the_other_gem`.

In the `gemspec` for `my_new_gem` I've included `the_other_gem` using `add_dependency`:

```rb
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = 'my_new_gem'
  s.version     = '0.0.1'
  s.date        = '2019-11-12'
  ...

  s.add_dependency 'the_other_gem'
end
```

And then in the `app/assets/javascripts/my_gem.js` in `my_new_gem` I have required the JS from `the_other_gem` the standard way:

```js
// Trying to require a JS file from another gem in my gem here
//= require the_other_gem
```

When I boot up a test Rails app that includes my gem in the `gemfile` with `gem 'my_new_gem'` I get a `Sprockets::FileNotFound` error when attempting to load any page in a browser:

```
couldn't find file 'the_other_gem' with type 'application/javascript'
Checked in these paths: 
  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/babel-source-5.8.35/lib
  /Users/me/Projects/my_project/app/assets/config
  /Users/me/Projects/my_project/app/assets/images
  ...
```

When I scan through all the above paths, the app is *NOT* including any vendor or asset paths from `the_other_gem` in that list, like I'm expecting it to.

Although it does make sense that if the path to the JS in `the_other_gem` is not showing up in my Rails app asset paths above that the JS file wouldn't be found, I don't understand *WHY* the path isn't being included.

If I include `the_other_gem` directly in my Rails app with `gem 'the_other_gem'` and also include `//= require the_other_gem` in the Rails app `application.js` directly then everything loads and Sprockets successfully finds the paths for `the_other_gem` assets.

Although this works, I'd rather not require folks to include the gem directly in their own Rails app, when I thought I could just tell `my_new_gem` to include it automagically for them under the hood.

So the mystery is, how can I get `my_new_gem` to include the right paths in the final Rails app so the javascript files from `the_other_gem` will load correctly? I feel like I'm missing something super obvious ... thanks so much!

Comment: I found this *very similar* question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531563/get-gem-vendor-files-in-asset-pipeline-path  But the solution for the OP (from 2011) is now the default gemspec setting - `s.require_paths = ["lib"]` - as stated here: https://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#require_pathsval